# How to iterate and save information from dynamic table with Selenium in Python on AngularJS website

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape for data from a dynamic table on a website utilizing AngularJS. I am using Selenium to scrape the website.

Currently, my problem is that I can not ID the dynamic table as there are no tags. Furthermore, the id's of the rows also have dynamic names in the form of strings which further complicates matters. Any help appreciated.

I have tried searching by ID/XPATH and adding them to elements list. No success.

The information I want is contained in a massive table generated dynamically with multiple parameters (The Collection Date):

```
<tctable id="tweb_EPVisitNumber_List_1">
```

There are multiple rows, containing multiple other parameters. An example of one small column I am interested in here below. I want to grab all the dates from all the elements in the table generated.

```
<tccol layout-xs="column" class="layout-xs-column">
<div>
<span id="web_EPVisitNumber_List_1-row-0-item-CollectionDate-label" class="componentTableItemLabel hide-gt-xs ng-binding ng-scope">Collection Date
</span>
<span class="componentTableItem ng-scope">
<span id="web_EPVisitNumber_List_1-row-0-item-CollectionDate" class="ng-binding">17/01/2019
</span>
</span>
</div>
</tccol>
```

The ID changes into a dynamic string as the table progresses, for example the next elements in other columns/rows will be:

```
id="web_EPVisitNumber_List_1-row-1-item-CollectionDate" 
id="web_EPVisitNumber_List_1-row-2-item-CollectionDate"
id="web_EPVisitNumber_List_1-row-3-item-CollectionDate"
```

etc.

My problem is that I can firstly not find the specific element in the larger table and I can also not iterate through it as the strings change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find some common property of the elements, and construct a locator based on it. For instance, in the given sample all interesting `span`s have "CollectionDate" in their IDs, but don't have "-label" (the column header has it).
So an xpath with that would be:

```
//span[contains(@id, "CollectionDate") and not contains(@id, "-label")]
```

Another observation - all "interesting" ones are `span`s in a `div`, which is in a `tccol`, that have the `id`; except for the first one, which is the column header:

```
//tccol/div/span[@id and not position()=1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To *grab all the dates from all the elements in the table generated* as the elements are [Angular](https://angular.io/) elements you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility of all elements located* and you can use the following solution:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  dates = []
  date_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tctable[starts-with(@id, 'tweb_EPVisitNumber_List_')]//span[contains(@class,'componentTableItemLabel') and normalize-space()='Collection Date']//following::span[1]/span[starts-with(@id, 'web_EPVisitNumber_List_')]")))
  for date_element in date_elements:
      dates.append(date_element.text)
  ```
- Optimized way:

  ```
  dates = [date_element.text for date_element in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tctable[starts-with(@id, 'tweb_EPVisitNumber_List_')]//span[contains(@class,'componentTableItemLabel') and normalize-space()='Collection Date']//following::span[1]/span[starts-with(@id, 'web_EPVisitNumber_List_')]")))]
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```